# Який правильний варіант назви криптовалюти «Біткоїн, біткойн, біткоін»?

Tags: фонетика

У слові однозначно присутній дифтонг, який звучить по-різному залежно від вимови, то як буде правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чинний правопис вимагає передавати такі випадки через «ї»:

> ## ПЕРЕДАЧА ЗВУКА J ТА ГОЛОСНИХ
>
> ### § 90. J
>
> <…>
>
> 5. Залежно від позиції та вимови в українській мові **i**, **y** (ігрек) передаються також літерами **і**, **ї** та **и**.
>
>    <…>
>
>    б) **Ї** пишеться після голосного: *мозаїка*, *наївний*, *прозаїк*, *руїна*, *теїн*; *Енеїда*, *Ізмаїл*, *Каїр*.
>
> <sub>[(«Український правопис», 2015, § 90.5.б.)](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p5b)</sub>

Тобто:  **біткоїн**.

Але остаточна норма в таких випадках, як я розумію, фіксується за фактом, тобто якщо фактичний вжиток дуже розбігатиметься з правописом, то, можливо, в словники (і врешті-решт як виняток у нові видання правопису) потрапить інший варіант.

<sub>Post Scriptum: Написання «біткоїн» також [підтримує Олександр Пономарів](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-41225133): «*Bitcoin* українською мовою треба вимовляти й писати так: *бітко́їн»*.</sub>